# Code after certain point not running without error

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a small snippet in a function for my tictactoe game to check if a square is empty by seeing if the list index of the choice contains the placeholder number emojis or not.  However, it wasnt working let alone running so I tried to print to debug it and it didnt print the emoji_moves list, only the plain string above('okay').  I get no error either.

```py
#small snippet
emoji_moves = ["1️⃣","2️⃣","3️⃣","4️⃣","️5️⃣","6️⃣","7️⃣","8️⃣","9️⃣"]
board = ["1️⃣","2️⃣","3️⃣","4️⃣","️5️⃣","6️⃣","7️⃣","8️⃣","9️⃣"]
else:
        if current_player == ctx.author.id:
          symbol = ""
          print("okay") #prints
          print(emoji_moves) #doesnt print
          if board[int(playermove.content)-1] in emoji_moves:
            board[int(playermove.content)-1] = symbol
            await display_board()
            return
          else:
            await ctx.send("That place is already taken, try another")
            await contain_move()
```

Full command for reference.  Relevant function above marked with hashes

```py
@bot.command()
async def tictactoe(ctx):
  embed=discord.Embed(title="Welcome to TicTacToe", description="A multiplayer game built by [Pricysquirrl#1641](https://discord.com/channels/@me/876492093248389120)", color=0x00ffb7)
  embed.add_field(name="Tag a friend to start", value="(@ them)", inline=True)
  embed.add_field(name="How to play", value="[Watch Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=USEjXNCTvcc)", inline=True)
  embed.set_footer(text="Play TicTacToe on Discord with friends!")
  await ctx.send(embed=embed)
 
  async def get_opponent():
    def check_opponent(input):
      return input.author == ctx.author and bool(input.mentions)
    try:
      msg = await bot.wait_for("message", check=check_opponent, timeout=120)
    except:
      await ctx.send("Game idle.  Ending...")
      return False
    else:
      if len(msg.mentions) > 2:
        await ctx.send("Choose 1 opponent please!")
        await get_opponent()
      else:
        global opponent_id, opponent_name,opponent_object
        opponent_id = msg.mentions[0].id
        opponent_name = msg.mentions[0].name
        opponent_object = msg.mentions[0]
        await opponent_object.send(f"{ctx.author.name} has challenged you to a tictactoe game.  Type **join** in the channel to join the game.")
        def check_opponent_confirm(opp):
         return opp.author.id == opponent_id and opp.content == "join"
        try:
          await bot.wait_for("message", check=check_opponent_confirm, timeout=120)
        except:
          await ctx.send(f"{opponent_name} has not joined.  Game ending...")
          return False
        else:
          print("brrr")
          global opponent_check_complete
          opponent_check_complete = True
  
  await get_opponent()
  
 
  global board,moves,game_on,current_player,other_player
  board = ["1️⃣","2️⃣","3️⃣","4️⃣","️5️⃣","6️⃣","7️⃣","8️⃣","9️⃣"]
  moves = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]
  emoji_moves = ["1️⃣","2️⃣","3️⃣","4️⃣","️5️⃣","6️⃣","7️⃣","8️⃣","9️⃣"]
  game_on = True
  current_player = ctx.author.id
  current_player_name = ctx.author.name
  other_player = opponent_id
  other_player_name = opponent_name
 
 
 
  def switch_move():
    global current_player,other_player,current_player_name,other_player_name
    if current_player == ctx.author.id:
      current_player = opponent_id
      current_player_name = opponent_name
      other_player = ctx.author.id
      other_player_name = ctx.author.name
    elif current_player == opponent_id:
      current_player = ctx.author.id
      current_player_name = ctx.author.name
      other_player = opponent_id
      other_player_name = opponent_name
 
 #######################################################################
  async def handle_move():
    global game_on,moves,emoji_moves
    await ctx.send("<@!{}>, it is your go!".format(current_player))
    async def contain_move():
      global game_on
      def check_move(move):
        return move.author.id == current_player and move.content in moves
      try:
        playermove = await bot.wait_for("message", check=check_move, timeout=120)
      except:
        await ctx.send("<@!{}> has made no move.  <@!{}> wins!".format(current_player,other_player))
        game_on = False
        return False
      else:
        if current_player == ctx.author.id:
          symbol = ""
          print("okay")
          print(emoji_moves)
          if board[int(playermove.content)-1] in emoji_moves:
            board[int(playermove.content)-1] = symbol
            await display_board()
            return
          else:
            await ctx.send("That place is already taken, try another")
            await contain_move()
        elif current_player == opponent_id:
          symbol = "❌"
          if board[int(playermove.content)-1] in emoji_moves:
           board[int(playermove.content)-1] = symbol
           await display_board()
           return
          else:
            await ctx.send("That place is already taken, try another")
            await contain_move()
    await contain_move()
        
#######################################################################
  async def display_starting_board():
    embed=discord.Embed(title="TicTacToe Game in Progress", description=f"{ctx.author.name} VS {opponent_name}", color=0x00ffb7)
    embed.add_field(name="Board", value=f"{board[0]}  |  {board[1]}  |  {board[2]} \n----+----+----\n{board[3]}  |  {board[4]}  |  {board[5]}\n----+----+----\n{board[6]}  |  {board[7]}  |  {board[8]}", inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Current player", value=f" <@!{current_player}>\n\n**Next Go**\n<@!{other_player}>", inline=True)
    embed.set_footer(text="$tictactoe: Play TicTacToe on Discord with friends!")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
 
 
  async def display_board():
    embed=discord.Embed(title="TicTacToe Game in Progress", description=f"{ctx.author.name} VS {opponent_name}", color=0x00ffb7)
    embed.add_field(name="Board", value=f"{board[0]}  |  {board[1]}  |  {board[2]} \n----+----+----\n{board[3]}  |  {board[4]}  |  {board[5]}\n----+----+----\n{board[6]}  |  {board[7]}  |  {board[8]}", inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Current player", value=f" <@!{current_player}>\n\n**Next Go**\n<@!{other_player}>", inline=True)
    embed.set_footer(text="$tictactoe: Play TicTacToe on Discord with friends!")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
 
  def check_for_win():
    global game_on
    if board[0] == board[1] == board[2]:
      game_on = False
      return True
    elif board[3] == board[4] == board[5]:
      game_on = False
      return True
    elif board[7] == board[4] == board[8]:
      game_on = False
      return True
    elif board[0] == board[3] == board[6]:
      game_on = False
      return True
    elif board[1] == board[4] == board[7]:
      game_on = False
      return True
    elif board[2] == board[5] == board[8]:
      game_on = False
      return True
    elif board[0] == board[4] == board[8]:
      game_on = False
      return True
    elif board[2] == board[4] == board[6]:
      game_on = False
      return True
    else:
      return False
    
 
    
 
 
  async def play_game():
    global other_player
    await display_starting_board()
    while game_on:
       await handle_move()
       check_for_win()
       switch_move()
    else:
      embed=discord.Embed(title=f"{other_player_name} wins!", description="TicTacToe Game Over", color=0x00ffb7)
      embed.add_field(name="Play Again?", value="Use $tictactoe", inline=True)
      embed.set_footer(text="Play TicTacToe on Discord with friends!")
      await ctx.send(embed=embed)
      return
 
  print(opponent_check_complete)
  try:
    if opponent_check_complete == True:
     await play_game()
    else:
      return
  except:
    return
```

Comment: No one is going to spot the error for you. You’re supposed to come here already with a *specific* question in mind, asking someone to debug the code for you is too vague and it is not the purpose of this site. A note for the future: the less code the better, you should try and add a code snippet as small as possible that still produces the same outcome.

Comment: yh I get that but i couldn't figure out what was wrong for hours, but I knew where the issue was so I thought maybe someone here might have had the same problem and could give me a quick answer, which was just one word in this case.  I can't just sit here and say oh well can't ask anyone because I don't understand why this isn't working lol

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to global variable emoji_moves.  Instead added global in other function only.

Answer (score 0):

You **don't want** to have defs inside other defs. I'd recommended to put all the other function outside the main (`tictactoe`) function. Try changing that and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by any number of things - if it's just bombing out without actually erroring then it's possible that the operating system is killing the process off in the background if it's a long-running asynchronous process?

Try what i suck at coding said, if it doesn't work with that alteration; you'll need to edit more details into the question - the question you've currently got is too large and unweildly for anyone to answer without spending hours debugging it themselves.